# Classifying the ActiveDocument.Selection in a Visual Studio Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

If I have a Visual Studio addin running, and I want to identify essentially what my text selection is over, how can this be done?

As more concrete example, I want the user to be able to right click on a class name, or method name, and when invoking a context menu action, be able to know programatically the name of the method or class that has been clicked. This is a bit like in resharper if you right click on a method, class (or property or field) you get a set of options specific to that type of code element.

Is there any way to do this from the document model?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I need - to understand what the code element is from a selection, use:

```
ActiveDocument.Selection.ActivePoint.CodeElement
```

which is an indexer allowing you to find out information about the code elements at that point.